# Thread timer multiple if statement not working

Tags: java, android, multithreading, google-maps

I am using intent and google maps to focus on a marker on the user click on the place displayed in `listview`. And i am using thread timer in `onResume()` to do so....
The problem is when i run my problem and use only 1 focus marker i.e. this code is running fine and focusing on the marker

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Thread timer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent intent = getIntent();
                        String restaurant_name = intent.getStringExtra("restaurant_name");
                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, restaurant_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        if(restaurant_name != null ) {
                            if (restaurant_name.equals("place1")) {
                                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(26.89192, 75.82441), 15.0f));
                                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(new LatLng(26.89192, 75.82441))
                                        .title("place1"))
                                        .showInfoWindow();
                            }



                            }else {
                            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "It was not", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }
                });
   /* Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, restaurant_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); */

            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();

    super.onResume();

}
```

as soon as I put another focus marker there i.e.

```
if(restaurant_name != null ) {
                            if (restaurant_name.equals("place1")) {
                                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(26.89192, 75.82441), 15.0f));
                                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(new LatLng(26.89192, 75.82441))
                                        .title("place1"))
                                        .showInfoWindow();
                            }

                            if (restaurant_name.equals("place2")) {
                                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(26.89510, 75.82594), 15.0f));
                                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(new LatLng(26.89510, 75.82594))
                                        .title("place2"))
                                        .showInfoWindow();


                            }

                            }
```

the second code does not focuses on the marker but the first one does..

I am bringing my intent my list view base adapter:

```
String value = holder.txtStore.getText().toString();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("restaurant_name", value);
            try {
                context.startActivity(myIntent);
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(context, "yourActivity is not founded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

What should i do to work for each focus marker i want to insert many , I have used if,if else,switch all of these but nothing is working??

Comment: In the first block, from the UI thread, you are starting a new thread to execute code in the UI thread ?!

Comment: Side note on code quality: the fact that you *can* use anonymous inner classes doesn't mean that you have to. Meaning: you might want to read about "clean code" (like the book from Robert Martin) in general; and http://principles-wiki.net/principles:single_level_of_abstraction specifically. Typically, your code becomes much easier to read if you do **not** have runnables in ifs in runnables in ifs.

Comment: did you debug the code, does the execution enter the 2nd if statement?

Comment: Yes it does enter in 2nd if statement i tried to use toast when i clicked on place2 it was showing place2 in toast.

Comment: Yes   I m  starting a new thread to execute code in the UI thread in first block..

Comment: Does it focus on anything at all when you put 'place2' to the intent? By the way where do the coordinates come from? It seems not the best idea to use hard-coded coordinates LatLng(26.89510, 75.82594). I think you'd better pass them to the intent along with the marker title.